# How to extract from a list based on user input

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sublist

The code contains two methods.

1. The ***Main*** which prompts the user for input and prints a sublist based on said user input.
2. The ***Extract*** method passes *query* from user input and adds all indices to `dbQueryList` to be extracted from `dbListing` and printed as query.

How does one to add to a `List` based on user input?

The primary issue is the *`if` statement* which contains the condition of 
`i.Substring(0, query.Length) = query`. This is meant to test the condition 'if part of the query exists in any index in `dbListing`, add elements to `dbQueryList` '.

I originally wrote this in Python and it worked perfectly fine. I'm learning C# and not sure how to change that `if` condition. I considered changing the code and use LINQ in the `foreach` loop but not entirely clear on how to implement that.

Looking forward to community feedback! :)

---

```
//**************************************************
// File Name:        autocomplete.cs
// Version:          1.0
// Description:      Create a method that functions like an autocomplete
//                   API and truncates search to 5 results.
// Last Modified:    12/19/2018
//**************************************************

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace autocomplete
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string[] database;
        private static string input;
        private static string query;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // user input to pass as query
        Console.Write("Enter your query: ");
        string query = Console.ReadLine();

        // dynamic list comprised of 'database' array
        List<string> dbListing = new List<string>();
        string[] database = new string[] { "abracadara", "al", "alice", "alicia", "allen", "alter","altercation", "bob", "element", "ello", "eve", "evening", "event", "eventually", "mallory" };
        dbListing.AddRange(database);

        // write results based on user query
        Console.WriteLine("Your results: " + Extract(Program.query));
        // keep console window open after displaying results
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // extract method passing query, return dbQueryList as query
    public static List<string> Extract(string query)
    {

        // empty list is initiated
        List<string> dbQueryList = new List<string>();

       // foreach assesses all strings in database in main
       // then, appends all indices of list equal to given query
        foreach (string i in database)
        {
            // compares query (from index 0 to length of) to all strings in database

            if (i.Substring(0, query.Length) = query)
            {
                // add to list above based on query
                dbQueryList.Add(i);
            }
            // if statement truncates dbQueryList to 5 results
            if (dbQueryList.Capacity >= 5)
                break;
        }
        return dbQueryList;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: 1/3/2019 18:30**

I made the following changes to the `Extract(query)` and it worked!

```
    foreach (string i in database)
        {
            // compares query (from index 0 to length of) to all strings in database

            if (i.StartsWith(query))
            {
                // add to list above based on query
                dbQueryList.Add(i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            // if statement truncates dbQueryList to 5 results
            if (dbQueryList.Capacity >= 5)
                break;
        }
        return dbQueryList;
```

Very excited that I got this to work! Please let me know if there are any further feedback about how to improve and clean this code if necessary! Cheers, everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are using `=` instead of `==` in the `if` statement.

In C# `=` operator is for assignment so what you are doing is trying to assign `query` to the expression on the left side, which is not possible. Instead use `==` operator which is for comparison.

Also, there is a more suitable method - use `i.StartsWith(query)` to check if the string starts with the given query. The current solution would work as long as `i` is not shorter than `query.Length`, in which case it would throw an exception.

```
if (i.StartsWith(query))
{
   ...
```

Comment: I agree, or use `IndexOf` if the condition is just that the text is in the string anywhere.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the feedback! I have tried `==` instead of `=` but I got an error on that as well for some reason.

I changed the line to:
`if (i.StartsWith(query))`

but I got the following error as expected:
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

`<Temporary local of type 'string[]'> was null.`

Any ideas on how to fix that as well?

@Dan D, `IndexOf` was attempted as well before posting this question but did not work either due to the parameters needed to pass in that function. The query will not be the same every time.

Comment: I have run the program and see the other issue now - in the `Main` method, you are declaring local variables `query` and `database` even though in fact you want to assign to the `query` and `database` fields which already exist. Instead of `string query = ...` you just use `query = ...` and similarly for `string[] database = ...` you should use `database = ...`

Comment: In addition - `Console.WriteLine("Your results: " + Extract(Program.query));` will not work well, because `Console.WriteLine` does not know how to output a `List<string>` instead, you should write a `foreach` or `for` loop to output the results